# Factor the Outputs of a Quadratic using Sieving

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, sieve-theory

I want to factor $(n-1)^3+1$ for many values of $n$.  Meaning, for every value of $n$ from $1$ to $N$ for some large $N$ I want a list of prime factors and corresponding powers for $(n-1)^3+1$.  We can see that $n$ divides out and is linear so its contribution is easy to account for with sieving, but then we are left with $n^2-3n+3$.

Obviously this does not factor over the integers, but its outputs can easily factor.  For primes larger than 3 we have:
$$\begin{align*}
p|n^2-3n+3\Rightarrow n^2-3n+3&\equiv 0\mod p\\
4n^2-12n+12&\equiv 0\mod p\\
(2n-3)^2&\equiv-3\mod p\\
n&\equiv 2^{-1}(3\pm\sqrt{-3})\mod p
\end{align*}$$
(to abuse notation a little with the square root).  Thus for $p$ to possibly divide $n^2-3n+3$ we need $-3$ to be a quadratic residue, which means $p\equiv 1\mod 6$.

For 2 and 3, 2 can never divide the output because $n^2-3n+3$ is always odd, and for 3 to divide the output 3 must divide $n^2$ so it must divide $n$.

But I'm a little bit stuck here: continuing to set aside 2 and 3, for larger primes we start by finding a square root of $-3$ say $r$.  Then we add $p$ to the list of prime factors of the output of the polynomial for $n$ for all values of $n$ of the form $\frac{p+1}{2}(3\pm r)+kp$.  I think finding a huge number of square roots will be very expensive using Cipolla's algorithm or Tonelli's algorithm though, so I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way I'm not thinking of.  I'm also unsure how to handle finding not just the set of primes that divides $n^2-3n+3$ but the powers of these primes as well.  However, working through the above computations again I think Hensel lifting the square root $r$ of $-3$ to $p^k$ and using the same approach would work for higher powers of $p$.  I'm not sure if there's a more straightforward way though.

Comment: "n" divides out, not "n-1". The quadratic sieve can be accelerated if the prime factors are of a special form, but I do not know in detail how this works. However, for huge $n$ we won't be able to factor $n^2-3n+3$ in general. But even if your list contains $10^{12}$ factorizations, there are no large numbers to be factored.

Comment: Good call, fixed.  Yeah using a sieve to factor n up to N and then using trial division or a fast factor finding algo like quadratic sieve to extract factors from $n^2-3n+3$ until the unfactored part is $<N$ could work.  I only need a method that works for $N=10^6$, so I can't sieve up to $N^2$ but even simply factoring all the numbers would probably be feasible.

Comment: I implemented a solution based on just factoring every number and another based on sieving as described here, and for comparison, factoring took ~30 seconds whereas sieving took 0.3 seconds.  I used the flint C library for factoring, which internally uses a mix of trial division, pollard rho brent, and lenstra ecf.